# Quiero eliminar un parametro de la url con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Buenas yo en distintos casos de mi proyecto pongo el id de un usuario, o un objeto en la url para usarlo como parametro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi .htaccess

```
#Activar rewrite
RewriteEngine on
Options All -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
#ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/modelarium3D-php/

RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php/ [QSA,L]
```

como puedo hacer para que no se vea esa cadena de id=<id_usuario>

Muchas gracias

Comment: Usa un parámetro diferente o mejor aun, usa POST para esas rutas.

Answer (score 0):

Podés crear una regla para ese link:

```
Rewriterule ^models/esteusuario.html/?$ /models/view/id=47
```

Salida: /models/esteusuario.html (te muestra el del id 47)

Si será dinámico, debes tratarlo con algo que lo identifique, en este caso el id.

```
Rewriterule ^models/([0-9]+)/?$ /models/view/id=$1
```

Salida: /models/x (te muestra el id x)

Podés reemplazar por un slug o algo que identifique ese usuario en la base de datos si no querés mostrar el id.

Comment: lo he insertado pero aun así no funciona, la url sigue mostrando id=<id_usuario>. Hay alguna regla genérica que haga que lo ultimo de la url si es id=$1 no aparezca?

Comment: Las reglas las debes crear vos de acuerdo a lo que requieras. 
Tené en cuenta en lo que respecta a las urls para generarlas si pones direcciones relativas o absolutas. 
Hay mucha documentación si buscas en google !
Solo te mostré un ejemplo de como hacerlo. básicamente 
Tambien la forma de "muestrear" un .htaccess es relativo a la configuración del servidor. 
Hay mucho que se aprende buscando documentación y luego a fuerza de prueba/error de manera local.